# Android create own View & Field

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a small comprehension problem: I tried to self-implement the Snake-Example because I'am going to implement an own View. SnakeView inherits from TileView which is a tile-based View and which loads simple square bitmaps (drawables) onto particular coordinates.

Well I don't understand the need of "attrs.xml" right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="TileView">
    <attr name="tileSize" format="integer" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I defined my own **attribute tileSize** of **type integer** which is **used in TileView**, right? This attribute can be found in the layoutfile as well:

```
<net.xyz.android.snake.SnakeView
     android:id="@+id/snakeView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tileSize="50" />
```

And now the confusing aspect: My TileView's constructor is:

```
public TileView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TileView);
    mTileSize = a.getInt(R.styleable.TileView_tileSize, 20);
    a.recycle();

}
```

... which should open a dynamic way to change the tileSize in the layout-file, right? But only if I change the 2nd parameter (default value) in my constructor, the size changes. The regular way - using the layout - doesn't change the tileSize.

I assume the layout-value isn't correct linked to this constructor invocation, is it?

Do you have any idea?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the declare-styleable tag and the class name have to be the same.

And the root tag of your layout has to have the attribute :

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your_package_name"
```

Then you can replace `tileSize="50"` by `app:tileSize="50"`